# UI Freezing Issue After Token Refresh in JWT in React App

Tags: reactjs, node.js, jwt

I'm encountering a problem in my React application where the UI becomes unresponsive or freezes after approximately 5 seconds or when refreshing the authentication token. I've implemented a token refresh mechanism using Axios and asynchronous functions

hole code is [GitHub](https://github.com/KuldeepSonara/JWT_LOGIN)

```
const refreshToken = async ()=>{
  try {
    const res = await axiosJWT.post("/refresh", {token: user.refreshToken});
    setUser({
      ...user,
      accessToken: res.data.accessToken,
      refreshToken : res.data.refreshToken,
    })
    return res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

const axiosJWT = axios.create() // create a new innstant

//Token refresh automatic evry 15m 
axiosJWT.interceptors.request.use(async (config) =>{
    let currentDate = new Date ();
    const decodeToken = jwtDecode(user.accessToken);
    if(decodeToken.exp * 1000 < currentDate.getTime()){
      const data = await refreshToken();
      config.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + data.accessToken;
    }
    return config;
  },(error)=>{
    return Promise.reject(error);
  })
```

[image to see just buffering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5P49.jpg)

i want refresh token after expiring current token automatic